# Is there a way to trim several characters (disregarding their combination) in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, trim

I want to remove leading and trailing spaces ( SP, \n, \t, eventually \r ) from strings in MySQL. Data already are on MySQL tables and I can't retrieve them for processing in PHP as this should be too slow.

I tried this kind of syntax:

```
UPDATE table set field = TRIM(BOTH '\t' FROM TRIM(BOTH '\n' FROM TRIM(field)));
```

But, this way removes `spaces, then`\n`, then`\t`in this order, and I want to remove all spaces disregarding their order (ie:`"\n\t \t\n\n\t  hello\t\n\n \t "`would return only`"hello"`.

I guess I need to create a function (`CREATE FUNCTION MY_TRIM`...), but before doing such job, I would like to know if there are easier ways.

Comment: why don't you try replace function.

Answer (score 0):

why not simply use replace

eg

```
update table set field = replace(replace(replace(field,"\t",""),"\n","")," ","")
```

Comment: I want to remove leading and trailing spaces only, sorry my question was unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
    UPDATE table SET `field`=TRIM(BOTH '\t' OR '\n' FROM TRIM(BOTH '\n' OR '\t' FROM TRIM(field)));
```

Comment: Just tried `select TRIM(BOTH '\t' OR '\n' OR ' ' FROM '\n\t \t\nhello\n\t \t\n');`, does not look working (even if the syntax with `OR` looks very interesting).

Comment: In fact, `'a' or 'b'` is considered as an expression; so `select trim(both 'a' or 'b' from 'aaxbb0');` returns `aaxbb`. Nice try anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This Worked for me:
`REPLACE(REPLACE(FileName, '\r', ''), '\n', '')`